# How to get dynamodb to only return certain columns

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

[image]

Hello, I have a simple dynamodb table here filled with placeholder values.

How would i go about retrieving only `sort_number`, `current_balance` and `side` with a query/scan?

I'm using python and boto3, however, just stating what to configure for each of the expressions and parameters is also enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within the Boto3 SDK you can use:

- [get_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item) if you're trying to retrieve a specific value
- [query](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query), if you're trying to get values from a single partition (the hash key).
- [scan](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan) if you're trying to retrieve values from across multiple parititions.

Each of these have a parameter named `ProjectionExpression`, using this parameter provides the following functionality

> A string that identifies one or more attributes to retrieve from the specified table or index. These attributes can include scalars, sets, or elements of a JSON document. The attributes in the expression must be separated by commas.

]You would specify the attributes that you want to retrieve comma separated, be aware that this does not reduce the cost of RCU that is applied for performing the interaction.

Comment: Hi @chris-williams, any example code snippet on how to write ProjectionExpresion with DynamoDB scan? I find on the web but didn't find any example using Java.

Answer (score 2):

to return only some fields you should use ProjectionExpression in the Query configuration object, this is an string array with all the fields:

```
var params = {
        TableName: 'TableName',
        KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk AND #sk = :sk',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':pk': pk,
            ':sk': sk,
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#sk':'sk',
            '#pk':'pk'
        },
        ProjectionExpression:['sort_number', 'current_balance','side']
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   table = dynamodb.Table('tablename')
   response = table.scan(
        AttributesToGet=['id']

        )
```

This works. but this method is deprecated, using Projections is recommended